# How to aggregate number of notes sent to each user?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Consider the following tables

```
group (obj_id here is user_id)

group_id    obj_id    role
--------------------------
100         1         A
100         2         root
100         3         B
100         4         C

notes

obj_id      ref_obj_id    note      note_id
-------------------------------------------
1           2                       10
1           3                       10
1           0             foobar    10
1           4                       20
1           2                       20
1           0             barbaz    20
2           0             caszes    30
2           1                       30
4           1                       70
4           0             taz       70
4           3                       70
```

Note: a note in the system can be assigned to multiple users (for instance: an admin could write "sent warning to 2 users" and link it to 2 `user_id`s). The first user the note gets linked to is stored differently than the other linked users. The note itself is linked to the first linked user only. Whenever `group.obj_id = notes.obj_id` then `ref_obj_id = 0` and `note <> null`

I need to make an overview of the `notes` per user. Normally I would do this by joining on `group.obj_id = notes.obj_id`but here this goes wrong because of `ref_obj_id` being `0` (in which case I should join on `notes.obj_id`)

There are 4 notes in this system (foobar, barbaz, caszes and taz).

The desired output is:

```
obj_id  user_is_primary notes_primary  user_is_linked  notes_linked
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1       2               10;20          2               30;70                  
2       1               30             2               10;20
3       0                              2               10;70
4       1               70             1               20
```

How can I get to this aggregated result?

I hope that I was able to explain the situation clearly; perhaps it is my inexperience but I find the data model not the most straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you simply put this in the ON clause of your join?

```
case when notes.ref_obj_id = 0 then notes.obj_id else notes.ref_obj_id end = group.obj_id
```

Comment: That works! It is a construction that I never used before :) But how can I get the (concatenated) list of notes (`30;70` etc)?

Comment: If you happen to have SQL Server 2017 (please add your version number in a question tag next time), you could use STRING_AGG. With other versions it's much harder, you may find this link helpful: https://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/sql-server/concatenate-multiple-rows-into-single-string

Comment: have added the tag! i'm on 2014 :(

Comment: If the answer + my comment helped you enough, please mark it as answer.